# Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531) | ImagePicker

Tags: typescript, angular11

I followed latest Angular 11 but still `const file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];` saying: Object possibly null

This is OnInit class:

```
imagePreview : string | any;
form: FormGroup | any;
```

This is imagepicker function:

```
onImagePicked(event: Event) {
const file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
this.form.patchValue({
  image: file
});
this.form.get('image').updateValueAndValidity();

const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = () => {
  this.imagePreview = reader.result as string;
}
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

[Main code snippets error is looking like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIltt.png)

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask], especially the part title "Write a title that summarizes the specific question".

Answer (score 1):

```
onImagePicked(event: any) {
    const file = (event.target as HTMLFormElement).files[0];
    this.form.patchValue({
    image: file
    });
    this.form.get('image').updateValueAndValidity();
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
    this.imagePreview = reader.result as string;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

**This worked for me :)**

Answer (score 0):

Try using if statement to check if files exists.

```
onImagePicked(event: React.FormEvent) { //use any if even React.FormEvent doesn't work
   if(event.target.files){
    const file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
    this.form.patchValue({
      image: file
    });
  ...
}
```

Comment: if(event.target.files) here : Property 'target' does not exist on type 'Event'.
  Property 'target' does not exist on type 'RouterEvent'.ts(2339)
and other error remained same :(

Comment: I'm also working with React doesn't seems casue error with me. I think you parameter type is the problme I have edited the post can try this.

Answer (score 0):

it's just that HTMLInputElement had the files type like this
files: FileList || null, so I assumed that File would also be null.
and the code will be like this.

```
onPickImage(event: Event) {
  const file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files ? . [0];
  this.form.patchValue({
    image: file
  });
  this.form.get('image') ? .updateValueAndValidity();
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = () = >{
    this.imagePreview = reader.result;
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file)
}
```